# python libraries in cpanel

Tags: python, django, web-hosting, cpanel

I am using heliohost's free service to test my django apps. But Heliohost does not provide me shell access. Is there anyway to install python libraries on the host machine?

Comment: I think you would get a better answer by asking this question on the web host's forum or support.

Comment: heliohost.net is not much of an active forum. :(

Comment: Maybe this belongs to [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to put them in your `PYTHONPATH`. Usually, your current working directory is in your `PYTHONPATH`. If that changes, you might need to add a path to it (maybe in each file, you should check, or one common file which is always included), and put the libraries there. You can do this with `import sys;sys.path.append(the_path)`

I'm not sure all of the libraries will work, but those which are pure-python, you should be able to copy/paste the source in a directory, and they will work I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should inform the support of heliohost.this server has very good support that help you or install any package you want